# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict_generator'

Tags: python

Tried to run a program using flask in pycharm ide.This is part of the code which throws the error:

```py
def finds():
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
    vals = ['a', 'b', 'c'] # change this according to what you've trained your model to do
    test_dir = 'uploaded'
    test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            test_dir,
            target_size =(224, 224),
            color_mode ="rgb",
            shuffle = False,
            class_mode ='categorical',
            batch_size = 1)

    pred= model.predict_generator(test_generator)
    print(pred)
    return str(vals[np.argmax(pred)])
```

Tried everything but still stuck here.Any idea how to solve this error?Or any direction as to how i am to proceed after this?

Comment: In the given code `model` isn't defined, where share the code where it is initialiazed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted the minimal code necessary to diagnose this problem.  Whatever is going on is going on with `model`.

I don't use flask but I'm going to stick my neck out here and say that `model` is coming back with a value of `Null`.  Whatever you are doing to initialize the `model` object is returning `Null` and that, I thnk, is what's causing the problem.

You can test for this in your code:

```
model = [whatever you have to do to initialize model]
if model is None:
    print("Model is None!!  There is no model.")
```

I'm assuming that you don't have the line `model = None` somewhere in your program...

Also, apparently `.predict_generator()` has been deprecated and you're supposed to just use `.predict()`.  That's not what's causing your problem, just keep it in mind.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes the problem was in loading the model. The methord i used earlier actually did not load the model and hence the nonetype error. Now i have saved the model in .h5 format and my program is able to load the model.